# Sum of nilpotent elements in a commutative ring is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to solve the following exercise:

An element $a$ of a ring $R$ is nilpotent if $a^{n} = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$. Show that if $a$ and $b$ are nilpotent elements
of a commutative ring, then $a+b$ is also nilpotent

I have seen that the demonstration proceeds as follows

How the binomial expansion is valid in a commutative ring, let $a, b \in R$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ such that $a^{m}=0$ and $b^{n}=0$, then

$$(a+b)^{m+n}=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n} \binom{m+n}{k} a^{k}b^{m+n-k}$$

when $k\leq m$ then $n \leq m+n-k$ and therefore $b^{m+n-k}=0$, in the other hand if $k>m$ then $a^{k}=0$, in any case $(a+b)^{m+n}=0$. But I do not understand how these inequalities allow us to affirm that $b^{m+n-k}=0$ and $a^{k}=0$.

All help is gratefully received

Comment: Remember that  $a^k = a^m a^{k-m}$.

Comment: What would the first term in the expansion be? Specifically, how is $a^0$ defined? Normally I would assume this would be the multiplicative identity, but it wasn't stated that R has a unity.

Answer (score 1):

When you take power $n+m$ for $a+b$, if $k < m$ then $m+n-k > n$, so the product $a^kb^{m+n-k}$ vanishes as $b^{m+n-k} = b^{n+(m-k)} = b^nb^{m-k} = 0$ for all $k < m$. For $k > m$ it is $a^k$ that vanishes, so all your summands vanish.